# LZ77 compression

Tags: python-2.7, compression

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LZ77 compression scratch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14685118/lz77-compression-scratch)

I'm building a LZ77 compression. I have read the whole file as a single string and tried to compress it. Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "deflate" is what you meant by "lz77", yes, there is. You could create `Compress` object and then call many time `compress` method on it. More here (search for `Compress.compress(string)`):

http://docs.python.org/2/library/zlib.html

Comment: I'm developing it from scratch.. This is my part of code where if I read a huge txt file it takes enormous amt of time.. Pls help me in this..fob = open(filename,'rb')
    original = ''
    for i in fob: 
        original += i
        #print original        
        
    
    """while 1:
        c = fob.read(1)
        #print c
        #print type(c)
        if c:
            original = original + c
        else:
            break"""
    #print original        
                
    lz = LZ77(original)
    stream = lz.Encoder()
    fob1.write(stream)

Comment: It's a bit difficult to read but it seems you are rebuilding `original` many times. See here how to do it better: http://www.skymind.com/~ocrow/python_string/

Comment: Also, this might by of some use as well: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html

Comment: Sorry this is ma code I post the wrong one..         fob1 = open(enter,'wb')
    fob = open(filename,'rb')
    original = ''
    for i in fob: 
        original += i
    lz = LZ77(original)
    stream = lz.Encoder()
    fob1.write(stream)

Comment: Why don't you do `open(filename,'rb').read()`?

Comment: There is no issue reading it from a file and storing it as a single string.. The issue i face is when i send tht string as a parameter to compress and write the compressed string in another file it takes loads of time..

Comment: Would you mind posting the code into your question, properly formatted, so we can look at it?

Comment: I did it here..pls look at this link               http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14685118/lz77-compression-scratch

Comment: I see. The problem might be that you do a lot of `+=` on strings. I linked above to better way of doing it, that is, have a list and append the chunks to it and finally `''.join()` the whole list for writing out.

Comment: I'll sure try and get back to u.. Anyways thanks a lot..

Comment: Even that way it is taking more time to compress..

Comment: In that way, you should use http://packages.python.org/line_profiler/ to see where exactly it slows down.